# Is there an app that can set color labels for individual files and folders?

Tags: nautilus, colors, macosx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have Mac like 'labels' on GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51777/can-we-have-mac-like-labels-on-gnome)

Is there any app that could set label color for individual file/folder like in Mac OS X?
Just something like this :

[image]

[image]

Comment: On Nautilus you can set color labels for folders, by going to Edit>Emblems & COlors. For  color labels on Files the equivalent would be using the Emeblems.