# How can I colour code my files like on a Mac?

Tags: nautilus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have Mac like ‘labels’ on GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51777/can-we-have-mac-like-labels-on-gnome)

Is there any way I can label my files with a specific colour in my folders? I know that this is possible on a Mac OS.