# Column view mode with Nautilus (like Mac OS X Finder)

Tags: nautilus

I found a feature request at http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/4496/ but it doesn't seem easy to get a column view with Nautilus while with Mac OS X it's a default feature.

Have I missed something or is this not currently possible?

Comment: Marlin and Pantheon Files support this feature. You can check them out if you're interested: http://askubuntu.com/a/185503/1992

Comment: @RolandTaylor Can you add that as an answer?

Comment: @JorgeCastro: shore!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Marlin and Pantheon Files have column view among their features. You can see how to install them here: https://askubuntu.com/a/185503/1992

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible with Nautilus, and as far as I know there are no plans to implement this.