# How to change the color of particular file?

Tags: bash

I want to change the color of particular file type:

- for .c files red
- for .out files green
- for .sh files orange

Like this, how to make these colors as default color for the corresponding file type?

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... But I got another method

Comment: Cool. :) Please post that as an answer and mark this question solved.

Comment: Posted my answer

Comment: Now please mark as the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed the color difference whenever try `ls -l` or `ls` commmand.

So I just used `$LS_COLOR` variable and modified it like this.

`LS_COLORS='*.c=01;32:*.out=31:*.sh=01;35:'`

[for more this source about bash](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `dircolors` command.
For example if you want to have the `Solarised theme`, download the required `dircolors` database file from this [link](https://github.com/seebi/dircolors-solarized)
To use it just do the following:

```
eval `dircolors /path/to/dircolorsdb`
```

For more instructions refer the readme of the previous link.

Some other useful links:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19219/how-to-colorize-output-of-ls

Answer (score 0):

By writing condition for gtk~.css or some action for Nautilus.
Or maybe just using custom iconset?

Need to say, such *terminal* command like `ls` is using folders and files coloring, and perhaps this feature have the base to be extended.

Look this answer: [Can we have Mac like 'labels' on GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/a/51781/38988)

Comment: I wanted only a way how to do it please steps or if already there is an answer plz provide some link, I am not able to find it

Comment: [Can we have Mac like 'labels' on GNOME?](http://askubuntu.com/a/51781/38988)